# Create a dictionary based on conditions for a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, dictionary

Let's say I have simple dataframe such as:

```
data = {'Col_A' : [0.75, 0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75, 0.25], 'Col_B' : [2, 2.5, 1, 1.5, 3, 3.5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

which results in this:

```
   Col_A  Col_B
0   0.75    2.0
1   0.25    2.5
2   0.25    1.0
3   0.75    1.5
4   0.75    3.0
5   0.25    3.5
```

What I would like to do is using a condition for both `Col_A` and `Col_B` and iterating through each row, should both match the conditions, I'd like to add that row to a dictionary.

So let's say if `Col_A < 0.5` and `Col_B > 2` I want to append a dictionary with `Col_B` and it's appropriate value.

In the case above I want the dictionary to be returned as `{'Col_B : 3.0, 'Col_B' : 2.5}`
I'm aware `Col_B` is repeated here, but I have a `df` of many many columns and many rows and I'm basically trying to get an idea of how often something occurs amongst a few things.

The code I would expect to be able to use would be something like this:

```
dict['Col_B'] = np.where((df['Col_A'] < 0.5) and (df['Col_B'] > 1.5), df['Col_B'])
```

Obviously I'm aware that's not going to work but it's the sort I was thinking. Any help would be great cheers.

Comment: First of all, `{'Col_B : 3.0, 'Col_B' : 2.5}` just won't work because keys are the same, what you could expect is something like `{'Col_B': [3.0, 2.5]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on conditions of Col_A and Col_B you want to get the values from Col_B?  You could do this:

```
# identify rows with matching conditions
idx = (df.Col_A < 0.5) & (df.Col_B > 2)

# put values from Col_B into your dictionary
dict["Col_B"] = list(df.loc[idx, "Col_B"])
```

This overwrites "Col_B" in your dictionary every time, but you can modify this to append instead if needed (I am not sure what you want to achieve here, so I don't know if appending is necessary for your application).

You said

> I'm basically trying to get an idea of how often something occurs amongst a few things

If you just want to count the instances of Col_A < 0.5 and Col_B > 2, just pulls the size

```
numEvents = df.loc[idx, "Col_B"].size
```

Comment: This has been a very helpful answer actually, thanks mate